# Logs of other users

Tags: developer-console, developer, roles

How can I see the logs of other users?

I am developing components, some users have problems while accessing them, it depends on their roles.
I can reproduce the issues when I log as a one of thosed users, but I am not able to see the logs in order to find the problem.

Are there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create user trace flags for your users. Go to `Setup -> Monitoring -> Debug Logs -> New`

Traced Entity Name is your user then create a new log level and adjust log levels as you desire. Adjust log start and expiration time and save. After this you see logs of your users in Debug Logs.

Comment: If only there was a better way to do it, anyway it help me a lot.
Thank you, for your help.